# How to round up 10.3 to get 10.30?

Tags: python

When we round off using python is there a way we get answer in 2 decimal place incase if:

```
round(10.3,2)
```

It will give 10.3.Is there way so that we get 10.30?

Comment: 10.30 is not 10.3 rounded up. It's a question of how much precision you are using to display the number. If you want to see 10.30, you need to use the proper output format statement to show 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

`10.3` is the same number as `10.30` so rounding has nothing to do with it. Try string formatting.

```py
n = 10.3

"{:.2f}".format(n)  # classic str.format
f"{n:.2f}"          # f-strings in 3.6+
```

Comment: *Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which... ...have already been asked and answered many times before.* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer